# Creating popup in C#

Tags: c#, popup

I want to create a popup in C# where there will be three dropdowns populated with values from Database, user will select the values and on click of Submit button on Popup the values the parent page will get updated as per the selected values.how to do it, can someone help me ?

Comment: which technology you are using ? asp.net or any other?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a new Form with the controls you want, and the events you want to fill them. You should call the form with `.ShowDialog()` to be modal, like a popup.

Once done, you only need to get the data on your main form. You can do that in real time with the change events on the controls of the popup (sending the selected data everytime you change it the value), or even using the `FormClosing` event of the popup to send the selected values before its closed, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF there is a [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx). In winforms you have to implement it yourself (one possibility is to use [`ToolStripControlHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.aspx) on the [`ToolStripDropDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.aspx), see implementation details [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17502/Simple-Popup-Control)).

Often beginners misspell *popup*, while meaning *modal* window/form. If question is that basic, please use search (google -> "C# show modal form", it should bring you [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to use another form. So any type of content can be added to it according to your need.