# Make a control appear on top of its parent

Tags: c#, forms

I need help with the following issue:
I have a panel inside of which I have placed a combobox and another panel. What I want is to show the child panel on top of the parent panel just like a combobox shows its items on top of its parent. Any way to achieve that?

[image: Panel]

Comment: Have you tried [Control.SendToBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Control.BringToFront](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ??

Comment: Do you mean the child panel is longer and should be displayed over the other panel? In that case, it should be added to the parent of the main panel (the form?) and placed in the correct Z Order (BringToFront)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty yes and this changes nothing.

Comment: @mrida, that's because the panel is child of the panel it should be shown over. A control can't be shown outside the bounds of its parent. If you move the overflowing panel to the form instead and then call bringtofront, you can position it as you want (as long as its not outside the form's bounds)

Comment: @Me.Name I need it to be in the same panel because else it will create problems i.e if the parent panel is contained in another panel that has scrollbars while the child panel is contained in the form itself. This will create inconsistency between the parent and child panel positions.

Comment: Just for curiosity, how come the combobox that is a child of the panel appears on top of its parent. Does it apply other approach than what panel does?

Comment: Yep, it shows a separate form when the dropdown is clicked. One that automatically disappears when another segment is clicked of gets focus, so it doesn't have to worry about keeping position with its parent.

Answer (score 1):

`Combobox` is composite control. Its popup part is in fact a *popup* window (similar to menu). It can even go outside of bounds of your form.

On your screenshot: child panel is a *child* of parent, so it will be automatically trimmed by parent bounds (or precisely, by parent client region bounds).

To go outside of parent panel, child panel should be a child of parent panel parent (to example, form), then, assuming z-order of child panel is bigger (use `SendToFront()`), it will be drawn *over* parent panel and can go up to the bounds of its parent bounds.

It is possible to *un-child* control, by removing it from parent `Controls` collection and adding it to some other parent collection, recalculating new `Location` (use `PointToScreen()` -> `PointToClient()` combo, perhaps there is even single method for this).

If you think to go outside of form bounds to be more like *combobox*'ish, then you need to implement it as popup window (see, to example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21179057/1997232)).